# PUN 2, Player A not seeing Player B's hat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

So currently im currently kind of new to multiplayer dev, and im trying to make a 2d multiplayer shooter, but the problem is. When **Player A picks Hat1** and **Player B picked Hat2**, after the players has been instantiated both players are seeing their own hat. Meaning, in Player A's screen, Player B has the same hat as Player A, Hat1. And in Player B's screen, Player A has Hat02.

so basically

- Player A selected Hat01
- Player B selected Hat02

Player A's Screen

- Player A with Hat01 and Player B with Hat01

Player B's Screen

- Player A with Hat02 and Player B with Hat02

If you could help me with thise, Thank you!

```
    void Update()
    {
       if(!PV.IsMine)
          {
             return;
          }
          else
          {
              PV.RPC("HatSelected", RpcTarget.All);
          }
    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void HatSelected()
    {
        transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(PlayerManager.selectedSkin).gameObject.SetActive(true);  
    }
```

Comment: `PlayerManager.selectedSkin` is the current player's selected skin?

Comment: Yes it is, `selectedskin` is an int so basically Hat01 is 0 Hat02 is 1.

Comment: So on PlayerB's computer selectedSkin is 1. You need to make it so PlayerA's computer tells the other players' computers that PlayerA is wearing hat number 0, and the other players' computers need to remember that. I don't actually know anything about Unity or Photon so I can't say how to do that.

Comment: It might be `transform.GetChild(2)` - that method doesn't fetch based on the parent structure you see in the editor, it's based on the order transforms were added / removed so it's pretty unreliable. Try `transform.Find` instead.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, whether its `Find` or `GetChild()`, both seems to give the same outputs